# git push all branches from repo1 to repo2

Tags: git, github, svn, gitlab, gerrit

i have cloned Repo1 from github to my local.
then added url of Repo2 using **git remote add new-origin**  command.

Repo1 contains 100 branches, so i cant checkout for each and every branch

i am trying to push all the branches to Repo2 using **git push new-origin --all**

but only master branch of Repo1 is pushed to Repo2.

**HOW CAN I PUSH ALL THE 100 BRANCHES OF Repo1 TO Repo2 without checking out to all the branches of Repo1**

***NOTE: i dont want to use bare or mirror repository***

Comment: Hi Romain, Repo1 is an opensource, i am experimenting with that sources. i want to copy complete Repo1 sources to my Repo2. and also frequently, i want to update the latest changes of Repo1 to my Repo2

Comment: Why you don't want to use a bare repository to achieve this? If you clone the original repo using "--bare", your push using "--all" will just work.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, actually i am experimenting the open source. so every time i need to update my repo with opensource changes. so i dont use bare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will only push all the local branches, so I guess you first have to checkout all of `origin`'s branches and then push them.

does this work?

```
git branch # should only show master
# check-out every single branch
git branch -a | grep origin | sed 's|remotes/origin/||' | xargs -I {} git checkout {}
git branch # should now show all branches
git push new-origin --all
```

(watch out - that's also push local stuff that wasn't in `origin`)

------ after comment - try this maybe -----

```
git branch -a | grep origin \
  | sed 's|remotes/origin/||' \
  | xargs -I {} git push new-origin origin/{}:refs/heads/{}
```

that should just list all of the branches on origin, and then push them all to new branches with the same name on new-origin

If there are spaces in any branch names (if that is possible) it probably won't work.

to see what it will do before trying, change the last line to this:

```
  | xargs -I {} echo git push new-origin origin/{}:refs/heads/{}
```

then if you are happy, remove `echo`, and see

Comment: Alex, Thanks for the response. without checking out all  the branches and without using mirror or bare, can i achieve this.

Comment: Alex, it solved my question. Thanks for your support. i am happy with this solution.